# What is the distribution of an affine transformation of a log-normal variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, lognormal-distribution, characteristic-function

Let $X$ be a log-normal variate and $Y = aX + b$ is the affine transformation X.

Is $Y$ log-normal? I suspect it is not.

Since $X$ is log-normal, its expected value is

$$
E[X] = \exp(M + S^2/2)
$$

The expected value of $Y$ is:

$$
E[Y] = aE[X] + b = a \exp(M + S^2/2) + b
$$

To characterize $Y$ as a log-normal variate I should write its mean in the same form of $X$ mean, and obviously reproduce the same approach to others moments.

Does that make sense? or Is there another way to characterize $Y$ as log-normal? For example, using characteristic function.

Comment: By definition $Y$ cannot be lognormal when $b$ is nonzero, for when $b\gt 0$ there is zero probability in the interval $[0,b]$ and when $b\lt 0$ there is positive probability in the interval $[b,0]$, neither of which is true for any lognormal distribution.  If you allow nonzero $b$, then this is called a three-parameter lognormal distribution.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that $Y=aX$ would be log-normal for a scalar $a$, (Easy to see by taking log of both sides of the equation). More generally, multiplying for log-normal distributed random variables is basically equivalent to adding normal distributed random variables.

Comment: The particular three parameter lognormal whuber refers to is also sometimes called the shifted lognormal.

Comment: Minor pointer to reference: wikipedia documents what happens to a log-normally distributed random variable when multiplied by a constant, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multiple,_Reciprocal,_Power